# filter out specific data from csv file only using csv module via python

Tags: python, csv

```
Person       occupation     partner        favorite_color
Anthony      student        Alissa         pink
Alissa       professor      Anthony        yellow
Jordan       professor      Khan           green
Khan         student        Jordan         orange
Benny        professor      Anastasia      blue
Anastasia    student        Benny          red
McCurdy      professor      Anastasia      purple
Alicia       student        Benny          black
Janet        student        Benny          white
```

Hello , I was wondering whether it is possible to filter and change my whole csv file so that every person that is a professor gets his student listed in another column for example:

```
V_I_P          color     sidekick    sidekick_color       
**Alissa**     yellow
                         Anthony     pink
**Benny**      blue      Anastasia   red
                         Alicia      black
                         Janet       white
```

and so on...

So if the person is a professor he is in the vip column and then if the students are assigned to a professor they enter the sidekick column.
Is it better just to create a new csv output file or just modify the whole csv file?
Is the csv module sufficient? On the internet I just keep on finding methods with the pandas module

Answer (score 0):

This is possible without Pandas using Python's standard library. A `csv.DictWriter` could help here. Also a `defaultdict` could be used to help create lists based on the `occupation` column:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

# Read the rows into lists based on the occupation
data = defaultdict(list)

with open('input.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input)
    
    for row in csv_input:
        data[row['occupation']].append(row)
        

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=['V_I_P', 'color', 'sidekick', 'sidekick_color'])
    csv_output.writeheader()
    
    for professor in data['professor']:
        person = professor['Person']
        csv_output.writerow({'V_I_P' : f"**{person}**", 'color' : professor['favorite_color']})

        for student in data['student']:
            if student['partner'] == person:
                csv_output.writerow({'sidekick' : student['Person'], 'sidekick_color' : student['favorite_color']})
```

Giving you an output CSV containing:

```
V_I_P,color,sidekick,sidekick_color
**Alissa**,yellow,,
,,Anthony,pink
**Jordan**,green,,
,,Khan,orange
**Benny**,blue,,
,,Anastasia,red
,,Alicia,black
,,Janet,white
**McCurdy**,purple,,
```

I would recommend you `print(data)` to understand what is stored.